# How to group custom menu points dropdown menu in R/flexdashboard

Tags: r, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I can add custom links to the menu using the `navbar` argument in `flexdashboard::flex_dashboard()`. There doesn't seem to be any build-in functionality group these custom links in a dropdown menu. Is there any workaround to get the same result as with the `data-navmenu` argument for pages?

[image]

**Description of `navbar` argument** 
Optional list of elements to be placed on the flexdashboard navigation bar. Each element should be a list containing a title and/or icon field, an href field. Optional fields target (e.g. "_blank") and align ("left" or "right") are also supported.